# @Query annotation not working with custom elastic search query

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch with java springboot java. When I run my query using curl it works fine but when I try to run it with Elastic search repository, I get an exception.

```
public interface UserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ActionsElastic, String> {

@Query("{\"query\" : { \"bool\" : { \"must\" : [ { \"term\" : { \"userId\" : ?0 } }, { \"term\" : { \"actionType\" : \"?01\" } } ] } },\n" +
        "\t\"sort\": [ { \"bookmarkedAt\" : { \"order\" : \"?2\" } } ] }")
List<ActionsElastic> findByUserIdAndActionTypeAndActionFilterOrder(Long userId, String actionType, String order, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Curl -

```
curl -X POST \
http://localhost:9200/actions/actions/_search \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Postman-Token: c06a825f-a9b2-49a8-9955-2d37cd2e3eae' \
-d '{"query" :  
{ "bool" : 
{ "must" : 
[ { "term" : 
{ "userId" : 1122 } }, { "term" : { "actionType" : "like" } } ] } 
},"sort": [ { "bookmarkedAt" : { "order" : "asc" } } ] }'
```

The curl returns data but when running spring project I receive

> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: no [query] registered for [query]
>
> at 
>   org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQueryBuilder(QueryParseContext.java:128) ~[na:na]
>   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.WrapperQueryBuilder.doRewrite(WrapperQueryBuilder.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.rewrite(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:263) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>   at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.rewrite(SearchSourceBuilder.java:879) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ShardSearchLocalRequest.rewrite(ShardSearchLocalRequest.java:244) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ShardSearchTransportRequest.rewrite(ShardSearchTransportRequest.java:171) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createSearchContext(SearchService.java:530) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:479) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:461) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeDfsPhase(SearchService.java:226) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$5.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:332) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$5.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:329) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.doRun(TransportService.java:662) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:675) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
>       ... 3 common frames omitted

Note - I don't want to use JAVA API by elasticsearch

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-03-01T13:31:31.537+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "all shards failed",
"path": "/content-actions/v1/actions"
}
```

Comment: Probably should include the relevant `import` statements -- so we know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `@Query` annotation you only need to specify whatever is inside the `query` structure of the DSL query, i.e. no `sort`,  `aggs`, etc, basically like this:

```
@Query("{ \"bool\" : { \"must\" : [ { \"term\" : { \"userId\" : ?0 } }, { \"term\" : { \"actionType\" : \"?01\" } } ] } }")
List<ActionsElastic> findByUserIdAndActionTypeAndActionFilterOrder(Long userId, String actionType, String order, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: But i need sorting does pageable sort works with custom elastic search querries and how do i sort it with field , also i want to perform sorting on a nested field

Comment: Sorting goes into Pageable indeed as explained in the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query)

Comment: I am asking how it works in case of custom query , if I want to search for data on a nested field

Comment: Even after removing from query it still gives error

Comment: The second parameter should be `?1` instead of `?01`

Comment: I have already corrected it , I  am doing sorting using Pageable
PageRequest(pageNo,size, Sort.Direction.DESC,"createdAt")
, had a little doubt whether psrting on field is tuned into querry by crud repository or the sorting is performed after the results are received

Comment: Can you clarify my doubt , whether sorting on field is implemented  into querry by elasticsearchrepository or the sorting is performed after the results are received

Comment: The sorting is done on ES side before returning the results.